# How do I truncate the SQL tables in VS2010 Data Connections

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I have VS2010 using a MDF file (is that SQL CE? I'm not sure).

All that data in that table is unneeded, and I want to truncate it.  Or I'd like to script out the data and redo it... but I can't find the commands to do so, not to mention TRUNCATE TABLE is not a supported command (WTF)

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that `truncate` is available on CE. Use `delete` instead. It will do the same for you in CE.

Discussed here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/5d4c571a-9875-4d84-a6ce-3a6f99a5e88d